# Alpha Shapes in pgRouting - missing FROM-clause

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I am attempting to follow [Anita Graser's post on creating alpha shapes in pgRouting](http://anitagraser.com/2011/09/25/a-closer-look-at-alpha-shapes-in-pgrouting/).

The article was written several years ago, so some of the functions have been updated and names have changed. I have updated the code and it all appears to work fine apart from the last step. I am getting the following error for the last three lines of code:

"ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "home_catchment10km""

```
    CREATE TABLE "os_m2".home_catchment10km AS
SELECT *
   FROM "os_m2"."m2_roads_vertices_pgr"
   JOIN
   (SELECT * FROM pgr_drivingdistance('
      SELECT gid AS id,
          source,
          target,
          cost_time AS cost
      FROM "os_m2"."m2_roads"',
      674062,
      600,
      false,
      false)) AS route
   ON
   "m2_roads_vertices_pgr".id = route.id1

   CREATE TABLE "os_m2".home_isodist (id serial, max_cost double precision);
    SELECT addgeometrycolumn('os_m2','home_isodist','the_geom2',27700,'POLYGON',2);

INSERT INTO "os_m2".home_isodist (max_cost, the_geom2) (
SELECT 600, ST_SetSRID("home_catchment10km"."the_geom",27700) <**ERROR HAPPENS HERE**
FROM pgr_alphashape('SELECT id, ST_X(home_catchment10km.the_geom) AS x, ST_Y(home_catchment10km.the_geom) AS y FROM "os_m2".home_catchment10km where cost < 600'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CREATE TABLE` statement creates a table, `home_catchment10km` in a schema, `os_m2`. The `SELECT` statement is trying to access `home_catchment10km` without a schema qualifier, which causes it to search in the public (default) schema instead. It should be `"os_m2"."home_catchment10km"."the_geom"`.